# Javascript in ten minutes: What is going on in this example code illustrating lazy scoping?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, naming-conventions

I've been re-reading Spencer Tipping's excellent [Javascript in Ten Minutes](http://github.com/spencertipping/js-in-ten-minutes) and for the life of me can't figure out what is going on in this example of using lazy scoping to create syntactic macros:

```
var f = function () {return $0 + $1};  
var g = eval (f.toString ().replace (/\$(\d+)/g,  
           function (_, digits) {return 'arguments[' + digits + ']'}));  
g(5,6); // => 11 (except on IE)
```

In particular,

1. $0 and $1 are being replaced by a function definition -- how does *that* function get evaluated? (Presumably by eval(), but I'm not seeing this).
2. What is the purpose of the single underscore argument in the function -- if I take it out, the code no longer works.  Presumably it's just a place holder, but why is it needed?

Answer (score 5):

That code scares me. It should totally not be used. (Unless there is some *really compelling justification to do so*; I am not aware of any<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>.) Also, there is *no* "functional programming" demonstrated in the above code, excluding *perhaps* the use of a callback. But heck, even C can trivially do that as there was no closure involved.

`_` is just a valid identifier (like `foo` or `_foo` or `$0`). Here is is used for "don't care" (the value is that of the entire matched text as the function is the "callback" for a RegExp match).

`$0` and `$1` are replaced by `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`, respectively (remember this is a *textual substitution* of the functions "to string" value!). It could have been typed out manually without a "macro":

```
function () { return arguments[0] + arguments[1] }
```

Or what I would have done:

```
function (a,b) { return a + b }
```

The rest (`Function.toString` and `eval(functionStr)`) is nonsense to support the "macro" stuff which relies on: `Function -> codeString -> alteredCodeString -> Function`.

This code requires a *working* `Function.toString` that can emit "source as it was". I am not sure when IE started supporting this, but it appears to work in IE9.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a little white lie, but the *only* place I have used such an approach involved IE in a Sidebar Gadget where the DOM could be "prematurely unloaded" when a flyout was retracted and some other messiness with trying to invoke a function in another `window` context. An all-about messy situation..

<sup>2</sup> The [Functional JavaScript Library](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) shows how much "macro magic" can be done *without* `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (also below).  This is a case of RTFM, as I wasn't aware (or had forgotten) that replace() could take a function as its second argument.  This was actually my confusion.  Your comment about the function being a callback for tne RegExp match is what tipped me off, so I pulled up the String.replace() documentation in the rhino book.  Not at all clear why this didn't occur to me before posting to stackOverflow, but thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I'll agree with **pst** here, this code is pretty scary. It's horrific for
readability. It's neat, though:

1. `f` is defined as sort of a placeholder function. It seems to be the actual
   *macro* itself; the numeric variables will be replaced when it's evaluated
   into `g`. They act as positional, variadic arguments which we'll see below.
2. `g` is where the magic happens: the function definition of `f` is converted
   to a string, and the numeric variables in the macro definition `f` are
   replaced with references to the indexed arguments for as many numeric
   variables there are in the definition of `f` (hence the regular expression
   and call to `replace`). The underscore is just used because we don't care
   about the first parameter to the callback for `replace`.
3. The whole thing is then `eval`ed, once `f` is essentially expanded to the
   following:

   ```
   function () { return arguments[0] + arguments[1] }
   ```

So, it's neat, in that you could define `f` with as many positional numeric
arguments as you wanted:

```
var f = function() { return $0 + $1 + $2 }
```

and it'd get evaluated to

```
function() { return arguments[0] + arguments[1] + arguments[2] }
```

Neat, but useless, arguably dangerous, impractical and hard to read.
I probably wouldn't ever use it.